# JsonProvider for Jersey 2.5 in Glassfish 4 does not mapping properties

Tags: rest, glassfish, jersey, gson, pojo

I am using jersey as rest client, but I have problems when application is actually deployed as war on Glassfish 4. When I run it from test it works okay, but in deployed application mapping to POJO return all properties as null.

I tried MoxyJsonProvider, JacksonJsonProvider also custom GsonProvider, but result is same.

Client constructor:

```
public DockerClientImpl(String restApiUrl) {
        restURL = restApiUrl;
        restClient = ClientBuilder
                .newBuilder()
                .register(GsonProvider.class)
                .build();
    }
```

One of get methods:

```
@Override
public List<Container> getContainers(boolean all, boolean latest, int limit, boolean showSize, String since, String before) throws DockerException {
    Response response = restClient
            .target(restURL)
            .path(CONTAINERS_LIST)
            .queryParam("all", all)
            .queryParam("limit", limit)
            .queryParam("since", since)
            .queryParam("before", before)
            .queryParam("size", showSize)
            .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .get();

    switch (response.getStatus()) {
        case 200:
            LOGGER.info("Container list succesfully retrieved");
            break;
        case 400:
            LOGGER.error("Bad request parameter");
            throw new DockerException("Bad request parameter");
        case 500:
            LOGGER.error("Docker Server Error");
            throw new DockerException("Docker Server Error");
        default:
            throw new DockerException("Unknown Error");
    }

    Type type = new TypeToken<Collection<Container>>() {
    }.getType();

    List<Container> result = response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<Container>>() { });
    LOGGER.debug(String.format("Response: %s", result));
    return result;

}
```

Container POJO:

```
@SerializedName("Id")
private String id;

@SerializedName("Command")
private String command;

@SerializedName("Image")
private String image;

@SerializedName("Created")
private long created;

@SerializedName("Status")
private String status;

@SerializedName("Ports")
private Port[] ports;   //Example value "49164->6900, 49165->7100"

@SerializedName("SizeRw")
private int size;

@SerializedName("SizeRootFs")
private int sizeRootFs;

@SerializedName("Names")
private String[] names;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getCommand() {
    return command;
}

public void setCommand(String command) {
    this.command = command;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public long getCreated() {
    return created;
}

public void setCreated(long created) {
    this.created = created;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public Port[] getPorts() {
    return ports;
}

public void setPorts(Port[] ports) {
    this.ports = ports;
}

public int getSize() {
    return size;
}

public void setSize(int size) {
    this.size = size;
}

public int getSizeRootFs() {
    return sizeRootFs;
}

public void setSizeRootFs(int sizeRootFs) {
    this.sizeRootFs = sizeRootFs;
}

public String[] getNames() {
    return names;
}

public void setNames(String[] names) {
    this.names = names;
}
```

And currently used Gson Provider:

```
@Provider
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, "text/json"})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, "text/json"})
public class GsonProvider implements MessageBodyWriter<Object>,
        MessageBodyReader<Object> {

    private static final String UTF_8 = "UTF-8";
    private Gson gson;

    public GsonProvider() {
    }

    private Gson getGson() {
        if (gson == null) {
            final GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
            gson = gsonBuilder.create();
        }
        return gson;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType,
            java.lang.annotation.Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object readFrom(Class<Object> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        try (InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(entityStream, UTF_8)) {
            Type jsonType;
            if (type.equals(genericType)) {
                jsonType = type;
            } else {
                jsonType = genericType;
            }
            return getGson().fromJson(streamReader, jsonType);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize(Object object, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(Object object, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        try (OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(entityStream, UTF_8)) {
            Type jsonType;
            if (type.equals(genericType)) {
                jsonType = type;
            } else {
                jsonType = genericType;
            }
            getGson().toJson(object, jsonType, writer);
        }
    }
}
```

Output in tests:

```
Container{id=a9e3a67979d392a0e48d534db5184ce717b0629c4255d4dbc1373f5a9140df51, command=/bin/sh -c /usr/sbin/sshd -D, image=frantiseks/apac:latest, created=1388002251, status=Up About an hour, ports=[Lcz.utb.fai.apac.entity.Port;@69ac536b, size=0, sizeRootFs=0, names=[Ljava.lang.String;@3098cc00}
```

Output from deployed application:

```
[Container{id=null, command=null, image=null, created=0, status=null, ports=null, size=0, sizeRootFs=0, names=null}, Container{id=null, command=null, image=null, created=0, status=null, ports=null, size=0, sizeRootFs=0, names=null}]
```

So could someone tell me why it do not work in glassfish? Or what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Just as first thing that I would check, did you try to print out the content of streamReader?

Comment: streamReader contains expected JSON when I run it as unit test, but during creating singleton in glassfish it does not write to System.out content of stream, so I think in glassfish is in use different provider probably default MOXy provider.